# Find number of open Programs C++

Tags: c++, windows

I need some help. I have an Windows program and it closes when user tries to open it more than 1 time. The way we do it is with FindWindowA so we close the software if there is another application with the Windows same name. We now want to let the user open the application 2 times at the same time. This is the code we use to find if the program is open:

```
bool TitleWindow(LPCSTR WindowTitle)
{
    HWND WinTitle = FindWindowA(NULL, WindowTitle);
    if (WinTitle > 0)
    {
        MessageBox(0, "You can not run the program more than 1 time at the same time", "Error!", ERROR);
        ExitProcess(0);
        return false;
    }
    return true;
}

void TitleCheckWindow(){
    TitleWindow("MyProgram");
}
```

Is there a way to find the number of programs that are running right now?

Comment: A program can have 0, one or several windows at the same time.

Answer (score 0):

`EnumWindows`+`GetWindowText`+`lstrcmp` but this is somewhat unreliable because the user might open/close the window at the same time as you are counting them.

To eliminate race conditions you need to use a kernel object. To restrict your application to a single instance, use a named [mutex](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/synchapi/nf-synchapi-createmutexw). To count something across multiple processes, use a named [semaphore](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/synchapi/nf-synchapi-createsemaphorew).